# Check if PE is 32 or 64 bit

Tags: php, windows, portable-executable

I am trying to figure out, given an uploaded EXE or DLL file if it is a 32-bit or 64-bit file. This is specifically for windows-based EXE/DLL files. Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Perhapps https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows and trying to write the a pattern matching function

Comment: I will give that a go, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have try this with python 2.7 as i working with Python.
Please check and conform the solution if any changes as i am new to PE file format.
Python code for this is ::

```
#Program to check PE file is 32 or 64 bit
import os
import win32file
import ctypes, hashlib

#Take File as input
resultPathFile = raw_input('Enter the path location of given file')
if os.path.isfile(resultPathFile) == True:
    print("File is present at this path"+"\n"+resultPathFile+"\n")
    #File check 32 or 64
    try:
        peFileCheck = win32file.GetBinaryType(resultPathFile)
        if peFileCheck == 6:
            print("The Given file is :"+"\t"+"64 bit x64")
        elif peFileCheck == 0:
            print("The Given file is :"+"\t"+"32 bit x86")
        else:
            print("other format file")
    except:
        print("Other file format")

else:
    print("File is absent at given Path")
```